# Restoring build.prop file after it got wiped

Tags: root-access, restore, nexus-6, build.prop

I have a stock + rooted Nexus 6 on Android 6.0.1. The editor I was using bugged out and wiped my `build.prop` file. I haven't rebooted yet, so the phone is still fine able to do things. There is no backup of the file.

What are my options here? Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go find and download the stock ROM for your phone and try to extract `build.prop` from it. Then place it in the correct directory and change its owner and permission.

Factory images for Nexus (and Pixel) phones are always available from [Google](https://developers.google.com/android/images#shamu).

Also there's [a similar issue](https://forums.androidcentral.com/nexus-6-rooting-roms-hacks/681782-nexus-6-marshmallow-6-0-1-accidentally-deleted-build-prop.html) from another website. You can download the ROm but **only flash system** so that the system partition will be restored. You may have to root again if you're not using a systemless root.